# Get class on item.below (child item of menu) inside <li> tag in menu--main.html.twig

Tags: theming, navigation, 9

Hi I can't insert class in child item of main menu and remove existing.
Part of my code looks like this:

```
{% for item in items %}
  {%
    set item_classes = [
    'menu-item-edot',
    item.is_expanded ? 'dropdown',
    item.is_collapsed ? '',
    item.in_active_trail ? 'is-active',
  ]
  %}
  <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(item_classes) }}>

    {%
      set link_classes = [
      'nav-link',
      item.in_active_trail ? '',
    ]
      %}

    {{ link(item.title, item.url, attributes.addClass(link_classes)) }}
    {% if item.below %}
      {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes.removeClass('nav-link'), menu_level + 1)  }}
    {% endif %}
  </li>
```

So all li tags return:

```
<li class="menu-item-edot">
```

But I need just top menu items return upper code and all other child menu items to return:

```
<li class="dropdown-item">
```

I didn't find way to remove class "menu-item-edot" and add "dropdown-item" to menu child items.

Please help

Comment: Use the `menu_level` variable to determine level and set the classes you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [sonfd](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/48114/sonfd) this my code now and it's working!

```
{% for item in items %}

  {% if menu_level == 0 %}

    {%
      set item_classes = [
      'menu-item-edot',
      item.is_expanded ? 'dropdown',
      item.is_collapsed ? '',
      item.in_active_trail ? 'is-active',
    ]
    %}

    <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(item_classes) }}>

    {% elseif  menu_level == 1 %}

      {%
        set item_classes = [
        'dropdown-item',
        item.is_expanded ? 'dropdown',
        item.is_collapsed ? '',
        item.in_active_trail ? 'is-active',
      ]
      %}

      <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(item_classes) }}>
  {% endif %}
    {%
      set link_classes = [
      'nav-link',
      item.in_active_trail ? '',
    ]
      %}

    {{ link(item.title, item.url, attributes.addClass(link_classes)) }}
    {% if item.below %}

      {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes.removeClass('nav-link'), menu_level + 1)  }}

    {% endif %}
  </li>
```